# How to disable tomcat 8 websocket server endpoint autodiscovery

Tags: websocket, tomcat8

I need to do some processing on the endpoint classes before they can be deployed and then deploy them manually. However it seems simply having a class annotated with `@ServerEndpoint` in my war is enough to deploy the endpoint in Tomcat and when I try to manually deploy later obviously I can't because the URL has been deployed already. Is there any way to disable the autodiscovery of endpoints?

Comment: the `@ServerEndpoint` annotation has an optional `configurator` attribute (jakarta.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator). Maybe it provides a way for custom loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source for the version I'm using - 8.0.28, there's no dedicated option. The code deploying the endpoints is in `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci`. The quickest 'shurest' hack is to put my endpoints into the `javax.websocket` package. I elected to use their `ServerApplicationConfig` hook instead which serves my purposes if with some minor issues.